# How can I declare a static function within a class?

Tags: c#

I would like to code a method inside the following:

```
namespace WebUx.Helpers.CSharp
{
    public class getExceptionMessage
    {

        < Method here >

        var exError = e.Message;
                    if ( e.InnerException != null ) {
                        exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
                        if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null ) {
                            exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
                        }
                    }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I should declare the class and method. I get mixed up over how best to declare and I think it should be static but not sure if there is a better way. Note that this method I want to have callable from many places in my code. I think I should probably return a string with the value exError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid those "helper classes" that could be used everywhere in the code I would write an extension method:

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static string GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
        }

        var exError = e.Message;
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
            if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null)
            {
                exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }

        return exError;
    }
}
```

then:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.GetFormattedErrorMessage();
}
```

I personally don't really like all those `StringHelper`, `ExceptionHelper`, `FormHelper`... classes when the only purpose is to provide static methods that are related to a particular type. Extension methods are made for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to create a helper/utility class for use throughout your code. I think you're on the right track and static classes/methods are good for this concept.

Static classes and methods are declared like this:

```
public static class MyUtilClass
{
    public static string GetExceptionMsg(Exception ex)
    {
                var exError = e.Message;
                if ( e.InnerException != null ) {
                    exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.Message;
                    if (e.InnerException.InnerException != null ) {
                        exError += "<br>" + e.InnerException.InnerException.Message;
                    }
                }

        return exError;
    }
}
```

And in your client code you would use the class like this:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var errMsg = MyUtilClass.GetExceptionMsg(ex);
    // display or log errMsg 
}
```

Comment: @M.Babcock: Extension methods would certainly work but in this case the OP is using some presentation-specific formatting code. I could easily see a utility class like this growing and needing its own members such as _lineBreak to be shared amongst several utility functions. Such concepts are better organized in specific classes, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void YourStaticMethod()
{

}
```

That is how you would declare a `static` method inside of your class.  It seems as you may be unsure if it needs to be `static` or not.  You need to decide whether or not this is functionality that should be called as part of an instantiated object.  If that is the case, then it shouldn't be `static`.  Otherwise, if it is a utility method or something along those lines, `static` may be the desired route.

If you wanted the whole class to be `static`, you'd do this:

```
public static class getExceptionMessage
{

}
```

Note that if you make the class `static`, then every member of that class will also need to be `static`.